# Server error "/" in the application SharePoint 2010 when filter option is clicked in list

Tags: 2010, list, custom-list, filter, asp.net

Have an error with a user on SharePoint, when user clicks on the filter options on SharePoint 2010 list the error below appears, it is not consistent but does happen regularly. Any ideas?

Thank you

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]
Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\abd9d59d\c0cf8bde\App_Web_viewpage.aspx_-1081523282.cphhoqlv.0.cs    Line: 0 
Stack Trace:

[FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.]
   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +98
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +59
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +124

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate.
         Client IP: 41.162.50.98
         Port: 53357
         User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3; Tablet PC 2.0)
         ViewState: 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...]

[HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +148
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +10991958
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +11076872
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +46
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +11072391
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +11071930
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +91
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +240
   ASP.VIEWPAGE_ASPX__1081523282.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\abd9d59d\c0cf8bde\App_Web_viewpage.aspx_-1081523282.cphhoqlv.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +599
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5459
```

Comment: is it the default list filter ? do you face this issue with other users?

Comment: Default list. No other uses don't encounter this. Deleted the user account on active directory and re added it. Still occurs on the computer or user that user accesses.